# SQL query regarding getting record having maximum date from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a SQL Server table like this:

`EMPs`

```
Id  Name    DateOn              DateOff     
-------------------------------------------------
1   EMP1    2020-9-4 12:00 AM   NULL
2   EMP1    2020-9-4 12:00 AM   2020-9-4 10:00 PM
3   EMP2    2020-7-4 12:00 AM   NULL
4   EMP4    2020-7-4 12:00 AM   2020-9-4 10:00 PM
```

Another example with query

```
DECLARE @EMP TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(200),
    AlarmOnTimeStamp DATETIMEOFFSET,
    AlarmOffTimeStamp DATETIMEOFFSET NULL
);


INSERT INTO @EMP VALUES(1,'Test1','2020-04-09 01:56:29.507',NULL)
INSERT INTO @EMP VALUES(2,'Test1','2020-04-09 01:56:29.507','2020-04-09 03:56:29.507')
INSERT INTO @EMP VALUES(3,'Test2','2020-04-09 01:56:29.507','2020-04-09 03:56:29.507')


select * from (
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by a.AlarmOffTimestamp  desc) rn
    from @EMP a
) a where rn = 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDH9E.png)

`Id` column is unique.

I want a SQL query, to get single record like from above example, I should get Id => 2,3 and 4th record; I'm confused how to use two column Max dates with group by statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select e.*
from emps e
where e.id = (
    select top (1) id 
    from emps e1
    where e1.name = e.name 
    order by e1.dateon desc, e1.dateoff desc
)
```

It is not very clear what sorting criteria you want; this gives you the record that has the latest `dateon`; if there are ties, `dateoff` is used to break them. You might want to adapt the `order by` clause of the subquery according to your exact requirement.

This solution is usually quite efficient, even against a large dataset. For performance, you want an index on `(name, dateon, dateoff)`. You may also try and add `id` in last position in the index, like `(name, dateon, dateoff, id)`: this makes the inde *covering*, meaning that the database could be able to execute the subquery by looking at the index only.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62ac17bc29f36fa72c5e1f537fef608a)**

Sample data:

```
Id | NAME  | AlarmOnTimeStamp            | AlarmOffTimeStamp          
-: | :---- | :-------------------------- | :--------------------------
 1 | Test1 | 2020-04-09 01:56:29.5070000 | null                       
 2 | Test1 | 2020-04-09 01:56:29.5070000 | 2020-04-09 03:56:29.5070000
 3 | Test2 | 2020-04-09 01:56:29.5070000 | 2020-04-09 03:56:29.5070000
```

Results:

```
Id | NAME  | AlarmOnTimeStamp            | AlarmOffTimeStamp          
-: | :---- | :-------------------------- | :--------------------------
 2 | Test1 | 2020-04-09 01:56:29.5070000 | 2020-04-09 03:56:29.5070000
 3 | Test2 | 2020-04-09 01:56:29.5070000 | 2020-04-09 03:56:29.5070000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simple `row_number()` function should be good in this case:

```
select * from (
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by DateOff desc) rn
    from myTable
) a where rn = 1
```

In terms of performance, you could define indexes on columns used to order and filter resultset, in this case `DateOff` is used for ordering, so it is good candidate for index.

Comment: sorry i didn't explained my entire query but it seem your query would just given me matching records but i want the other records too like 2nd 3rd and 4th too